# Using created classes

Tags: python

I have this class Person created:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):

        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._gender = gender
        self._friend = None

    def __eq__(self, person):
        return str(self) == str(person)

    def __str__(self):
        if self._gender == 'M':
            title = 'Mr'
        elif self._gender == 'F':
            title = 'Miss'
        else:
            title = 'Ms'

        return title + ' ' + self._name + ' ' + str(self._age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person: ' + str(self)

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_age(self):
        return self._age

    def get_gender(self):
        return self._gender

    def set_friend(self, friend):
        self._friend = friend

    def get_friend(self):
        return self._friend
```

I now need to have 3 functions:

1. Using the Person class, write a function `print_friend_info(person)` which accepts a single argument, of type Person, and:

   - prints out their name
   - prints out their age
   - if the person has any friends, prints 'Friends with {name}'
2. A function `create_fry()` which returns a Person instance representing Fry. Fry is 25 and his full name is 'Philip J. Fry'
3. A function `make_friends(person_one, person_two)` which sets each argument as the friend of the other.

And this is what I've got:

```
def print_friend_info(person):
    person= Person
    person_name=person.get_name(person)
    person_age=person.get_age(person)
    person_gender=person.get_gender(person)
    person_friends=person.get_friend(person)
    return person_name, person_age, person_gender, person_friends
    """print (person_name)
    print (person_age)
    print ('Friends with {'+person_friends+'}')"""


def create_fry():
    fry=Person("Philip J. Fry", 23, "M")
    return fry


def make_friends(person_one,person_two):
    return person_one.set_friend(person_two)
```

And the error handler says `"type object 'Person' has no attribute '_name'"`

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but that `Person` class is horribly unpythonic. There's no need for `get_name` and similar methods (though getter methods are common in other languages). A more natural design in Python would either just use plain attributes or `property` descriptors (which work just like regular attributes for the code that's using them, but are implemented with getter and/or setter functions).

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove this line

```
person= Person
```

from the `print_friend_info(person):` function.

That line doesn't create a new Person instance, and even if it did you wouldn't need to. You already get the person passed in as parameter, all you need to do there is retrieve his information.

Since classes are objects in python, by doing `person= Person` you are just saying that `person` is the same as `Person`. Then when you try to  `get_name` on `person`, that doesn't work because `person` is not an instance of a class, it is a class object. Therefore it has no `_name` attribute. It will only have a `_name` attribute after you instantiate it with the proper parameters.

---

> it still dosn't print the info needed

```
return person_name, person_age, person_gender, person_friends
"""print (person_name)
print (person_age)
print ('Friends with {'+person_friends+'}')"""
```

This code doesn't seem right. Instead of printing the data, it returns the data. The text between `"""` does nothing because you have already left the function with `return`

Should probably be replaced with

```
print (person_name)
print (person_age)
print ('Friends with {'+person_friends+'}')
return  # this is not necessary, but it's better to be explicit.
```

Comment: i've deleted that line, but it still dosn't print the info needed

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand what you try to put into print_friend_info, if the parameter "person" is an instance already

I think your problem is this line

```
person = Person
```

by doing that, you just override person which is an instance and replace it with just a definition of class Person

Try to remote that line, and see what happend

Comment: How do you invoke that function? It depends on the parameter you pass to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `Person` object, say with a label `person`, you can access its functions like so:

```
>>> person = Person('Pete', 43, 'Male')
>>> person.get_age()
43
```

You don't need to pass `person` to the member function `get_age`:

```
>>> person.get_age(person)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: get_age() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

But the definition of `get_age` does have a parameter, `self`:

```
def get_age(self):
    return self._age
```

This is implicitly passed to the function when you call it on an object. So `person` is being passed as `self`. You can see in the error message above that we were passing two parameters, the implicit `self` `person`, and the (wrong, unneeded) explicit `person`.

`self._age` is the same as `person._age`, but is encapsulated, and hidden behind your *'getter'* interface.

So, to fix your code, get rid of:

```
person = Person
```

and change calls like `person.get_age(person)`, `to person.get_age()`.